# Google sketchup , how to display the model in iPhone/iPad?

Tags: ios, sketchup

Is there any objective-c library or workaround solution to display the skp file ?
Thanks

Comment: The SketchUp website recently added a showcase section where they use WebGL to display SketchUp models. The solution is not available to third parties yet, but they are indicating it will be soon. Keen an eye out. http://www.google.com/sketchup/showcase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are going to need to work something with OpenES, try the unity engine. You'll be able to export in some format from sketch up to Unity.